# Azure Redis Cache data loss?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-redis-cache

I have a Node.js application that receives data via a Websocket connection and pushes each message to an Azure Redis cache. It stores a persistent array of messages in a variable for downstream use, and at regular intervals syncs that array from the cache. Bit convoluted, but at a later point I want to separate out the half of the application that writes to the cache from the half of it that reads from it..

At around 02:00 GMT, based on the Azure portal stats, I appear to have started getting "cache misses" on that sync, which last for a couple of hours before I started getting "cache hits" again sometime around 05:00.

The cache misses correspond to a sudden increase in CPU usage, which peaks at around 05:00. And when I say peaks, I mean it hits 81%, vs a previous max of about 6%.

So sometime around 05:00, the CPU peaks, then drops back to normal, the "cache misses" go away, but looking at the cache memory usage, I drop from about 37.4mb used to about 3.85mb used (which I suspect is the "empty" state), and the list that's being used by this application was emptied.

The only functions that the application is running against the cache are LPUSH and LRANGE, there's nothing that has any capability to remove data, and in case anybody was wondering, when the CPU ramped up the memory usage did not so there's nothing to suggest that rogue additions of data cropped up.

It's only on the Basic plan, so I'm not expecting it to be invulnerable or anything, but even without the replication features of the Standard plan I had expected that it wouldn't be in a position to completely wipe itself - I was under the impression that Redis periodically writes itself to disk and restores from that when it recovers from an error.

All of which is my way of asking:

1. Does anybody have any idea what might have happened here?
2. If this is something that others have been able to accidentally trigger themselves, are there any gotchas I should be looking out for that I might have in other applications using the same cache that could have caused it to fail so catastrophically?
3. I would welcome a chorus of people telling me that the Standard plan won't suffer from this sort of issue, because I've already forked out for it and it would be nice to feel like that was the right call.

Many thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Here my thoughts:

Azure Redis Cache stores information in memory. By default, it won't save a "backup" on disk, so, you had information in memory, for some reason the server got restarted and you lost your data.

PS: See this feedback, there is no option to persist information on disk using azure-redis cache yet http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169382-cache/suggestions/6022838-redis-cache-should-also-support-persistence

Comment: BTW: the in-memory thing is regardless of whether you are chose Basic or Standard plan.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you don't use Basic plan. Basic plan doesn't suppose SLA and from my expirience it lost data quite often
2. Standard plan provides SLA and utilize 2 instances of Redis Cache. It's quite stable and it didn't lose our data, although such case still possible.
3. Now, if you're going to use Azure Redis as database, but not as a cache you need to utilize data persistance feature, which is already available in Azure Redis Cache Premium Tier: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-premium-tier-intro (see Redis data persistence)

Answer (score 0):

James, using the Standards instance should give you much improved availability.

With the Basic tier any Azure Fabric update to the Master Node (or hardware failure), will cause you to loose all data.

Azure Redis Cache does not support persistence (writing to disk/blob) yet, even in Standard Tier. But the Standard tier does give you a replicated slave node, that can take over if you Master goes down.